# Getting error while debugging a C program in gdb mode

Tags: c

When I tried to run binary in gdb mode I am getting the below mentioned error message .Please find the error message in the attachment

```
(gdb)  r /devl/aaa/BINARY/pfm.sql_Kavitha /devl/aaa/AVP/OCT_TEST /devl/aaa/ASAPDATA/READONLY /devl/aaa/ASAPDATA/READONLY 17 kk12345
Starting program:  /devl/aaa/BINARY/pfm.sql_Kavitha /devl/aaa/AVP/OCT_TEST /devl/aaa/ASAPDATA/READONLY /devl/aaa/ASAPDATA/READONLY 17 kk12345
**No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.**
```

Please let me know if anybody knows how to resolve this issue.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Invoke gdb as:

```
gdb /devl/aaa/BINARY/pfm.sql_Kavitha
```

and then run the program from within gdb as:

```
(gdb) r /devl/aaa/BINARY/pfm.sql_Kavitha /devl/aaa/AVP/OCT_TEST /devl/aaa/ASAPDATA/READONLY /devl/aaa/ASAPDATA/READONLY 17 kk12345
```

`(gdb)` above is the prompt.

If you want to be able to specify the program to execute from within gdb, use `file` command, as the error message says:

```
(gdb) file /devl/aaa/BINARY/pfm.sql_Kavitha
```

followed by the `r` command as above.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with the file you are trying to run from gdb -- either it is a corrupted file or the path is wrong. Try "gdb {filename}".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a single command, you will need two. One to *specify* the binary file and another to *run* the binary. In your case the commands are:

```
file /devl/aaa/BINARY/pfm.sql_Kavitha
run /devl/aaa/AVP/OCT_TEST /devl/aaa/ASAPDATA/READONLY /devl/aaa/ASAPDATA/READONLY 17 kk12345
```

Alternatively, instead of using the `file` command, you can give the binary name to gdb as an argument when you start gdb. Also notice the syntax of the `run` command. The binary name is not repeated!